# How to fine tune InceptionV3 in Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning, batch-normalization, image-classification

I am trying to train a classifier based on the InceptionV3 architecture in Keras.
For this I loaded the pre-trained InceptionV3 model, without top, and added a final fully connected layer for the classes of my classification problem. In the first training I froze the InceptionV3 base model and only trained the final fully connected layer.

In the second step I want to "fine tune" the network by unfreezing a part of the InceptionV3 model.
Now I know that the InceptionV3 model makes extensive use of BatchNorm layers. It is recommended ([link to documentation](https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#finetuning)), when BatchNorm layers are "unfrozen" for fine tuning when transfer learning, to keep the mean and variances as computed by the BatchNorm layers fixed. This should be done by setting the BatchNorm layers to inference mode instead of training mode.
Please also see: [What's the difference between the training argument in call() and the trainable attribute?](https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-the-training-argument-in-call-and-the-trainable-attribute)

**Now my main question is: how to set ONLY the BatchNorm layers of the InceptionV3 model to inference mode?**

Currently I set the whole InceptionV3 base model to inference mode by setting the "training" argument when assembling the network:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape)
# Scale the 0-255 RGB values to 0.0-1.0 RGB values
x = layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)(inputs)
# Set include_top to False so that the final fully connected (with pre-loaded weights) layer is not included.
# We will add our own fully connected layer for our own set of classes to the network.
base_model = keras.applications.InceptionV3(input_shape=input_shape, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
x = base_model(x, training=False)
# Classification block
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
x = layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
```

What I don't like about this, is that in this way I set the whole model to inference mode which may set some layers to inference mode which should not be.

Here is the part of the code that loads the weights from the initial training that I did and the code that freezes the first 150 layers and unfreezes the remaining layers of the InceptionV3 part:

```
model.load_weights(load_model_weight_file_name)
for layer in base_model.layers[: 150]:
    layer.trainable = False
for layer in base_model.layers[ 150:]:
    layer.trainable = True
```

The rest of my code (not shown here) are the usual compile and fit calls.

Running this code seems to result a network that doesn't really learn (loss and accuracy remain approximately the same). I tried different orders of magnitude for the optimization step size, but that doesn't seem to help.

Another thing  that I observed it that when I make the whole InceptionV3 part trainable

```
base_model.trainable = True
```

that the training starts with an accuracy server orders of magnitude smaller than were my first training round finished (and of course a much higher loss). Can someone explain this to me? I would at least expect the training to continue were it left off in terms of accuracy and loss.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
for layer in base_model.layers:
    if isinstance(layer ,tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization):
        layer.trainable=False
```

This will iterate over each layer and check the type, setting to inference mode if the layer is BatchNorm.

As for the low starting accuracy during transfer learning, you're only loading the weights and not the optimiser state (as would occur with a full `model.load()` which loads architecture, weights, optimiser state etc).

This doesn't mean there's an error, but if you must load weights only just let it train, the optimiser will configure eventually and you should see progress. Also as you're potentially over-writing the pre-trained weights in your second run, make sure you use a lower learning rate so the updates are small in comparison i.e. fine-tune the weights rather than blast them to pieces.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but that is not what I am looking for I guess. Because I do want those layers to learn (because they have to learn the gamma and beta weights, right?), I only don't want them to be in training mode to avoid that the layer will calculate the mean and variance for a batch.

Comment: I don't really understand your explanation for the accuracy. When I load the weights, then in the beginning of training, the network will approximately be the same as before and therefore the classification result will approximately be the same. Even in the first steps of the first epoch I see a much much lower accuracy (and higher loss) than before.

Comment: Your question was "how to set ONLY the BatchNorm layers of the InceptionV3 model to inference mode" and this is exactly how you would do that. I think there might be some confusion in terminology here - if you want the layers to learn (`layer.trainable=True`) then by definition they are in training mode. Setting trainable = false is the definition of inference mode, and is what keras/tf does automatically when you call `base_model.predict`. You can't have the layer learn and not be in training mode.

Comment: Just to clarify something on "It is recommended, when BatchNorm layers are "unfrozen" for fine tuning when transfer learning" - here "unfrozen" means setting layer.trainable = True, with the assumption that you freeze/set trainable=False to all the other layers. You can either freeze the entire model and add some additional layers on top, or unfreeze all/some of the layers and choose a low learning rate to slightly tweak the entire model weights.

Comment: On the accuracy comment - when you load the weights only (and not the optimizer etc) then yes the model weights will be identical, but the optimizer also retains a state when you train a model, and so if you're not loading the optimizer from the first training round (i.e. the optimizer state is reset) then it will take some initial batches for it to re-calculate its state, which is why your accuracy is much lower than before at the start. Have you allowed it to run to see if the accuracy improves?

Comment: Well according to Keras documentation, a layer being trainable and running in training mode are two orthogonal concepts: https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#whats-the-difference-between-the-training-argument-in-call-and-the-trainable-attribute
I want some BatchNorm layers to be unfrozen but to be in inference mode, as suggested in the Keras documentation about transfer learning: https://keras.io/guides/transfer_learning/#finetuning